# ReSharper slowing down VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I love the ReSharper features but when I installed it onto my project on my laptop VS2010 is running a lot (read unusable) slower:
Stats are

```
Windows 7
4GB RAM
Intel 2 Core Duo @ 2.00GHz
VS 2010
ReSharper 6.1
32 Bit Architecture
```

I'm assuming this should be enough to run the program so possible reasons I can think of are

- other plugins causing conflicts / overloading VS
- too many ReSharper errors (it's old code so will need cleaning)

Does anyone else have suggestions as to what this could be?

EDIT: the solution is 15 separate projects with 20 - 30 cs files. Some are very large (antlr generated)

EDIT: After turning off the 'solution wide analyse feature' the memory usage is down to 500Mb and it's running fine.

Comment: 1. Get more memory. 2. Use a SSD.

Comment: well for me i always had to turn off the analyser(the red/green ligh in bottom bar of VS) for big project...

Comment: How big is the solution? IMX R# copes well with many *classes and/or files*, but less well (*much* less well) with many *projects*

Comment: @Oded - possibly the problem but the profiler shows 1.4 GB free

Comment: devenv is a 32bit process that can access a maximum of 3gb.

Comment: I love resharper too, but it I just had to pull the plug.

Comment: @Sam1 new to the tool - how do I turn of the analyser?

Comment: @directedbit right click that red/green icon on bottom bar right hand and select disable

Comment: @Sam1 thanks - that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Don't forget that a Core 2 Duo is between 3 to 6 years old depending on the model, which is half an eternity in the computer hardware world. ReSharper is quite CPU intensive. Upgrade the whole computer if you can, or use R# 5.1 which has less features but requires a less powerful machine.

Comment: I had similar issues in VS 2008, but things improved dramatically when I switched to VS 2010. I'm on a 64-bit machine with 8GB, though. My workaround for 2008 was to suspend Resharper while coding and then activate it before check-in to clean up my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sometimes need to open old projects where there are many big files with resharper errors.

My solution is to exclude these files from the resharper analysis ("Edit items to skip" under the Code inspection settings).

I lose some intellisense but VS becomes usable again. If I need to do a lot of work in one of these big files I enable them one by one.

Answer (score 6):

ReSharper tends to bloat memory usage of Visual Studio (check devenv.exe under the Processes tab in Task Manager). If you have a solution containing many projects, and are running lots of other things on your PC you may find that memory is being swapped to disk a lot.

Possible solutions:

- Get more RAM
- Run fewer programs at once

Answer (score 1):

For me I was using Resharper with Visual Studio 2013 with 30+ projects, and even disabling solution-wide analysis in addition to Ultimate Guide were not good enough in total. I have 16GB RAM - so memory was probably not the issue.

Resharper does not scale up that well with increasing number of projects.

How I fixed those issues were (in addition to the Ultimate Guide (suggestions there are great))

1. Unload any projects that are not directly related
2. Edit items to skip as Adrianm suggested
3. Go to Resharper Menu => Options => CodeInspection => Inspection Severity. Go to your programming language (C# for me). Among the options there you will see many inspection severities for different issues (a few hundreds). Most of them I did not care, some of them I used very frequently. I set the severity to "Do not show" for many of the severities that I did not care.
4. Since Resharper also had reduced performance after a while, and I really had some suo settings that I liked in my solution (some less frequent projects unloaded, debug exceptions enabled etc.), I took a backup of them. First delete the suo file (user settings) in the solution folder. After that set the settings you want in Visual studio, and click save all. After that take a backup for that suo file. Every time resharper slows, if suspend/resume does not help, I close the solution, delete the current suo file, restore the suo file from the backup and start the solution back again.

All those steps now are providing me a very good pleasant Resharper performance with my Visual studio. It helps to invest as early as you can. Especially for item 3 when you think about it you are actually running many checks in parallel that you do not care about.

I know this is an older thread - yet the portions I wrote here are kind of independent from Visual Studio and Resharper version and I could not find this anywhere else on the web.

Hope it helps to anyone seeing similar performance issues with Resharper.

Edit 1: Btw - once you have that working it helps to get a backup of the resharper settings in case they get lost. If you are sharing the project among multiple developers, putting it to git/SVN might be a good idea as well.